# What Gantt Chart software can be coupled tightly with the development process for minimum effort required?

Tags: gantt, trac

From a software developer's point of view, maintaining a gantt chart (such as marking off tasks as complete or reassigning them, etc) can become cumbersome when dealing with a separate piece of software to that of the development process.

Currently, I utilise [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) to create/manage tasks for the project, and have an SVN hook which marks them complete as I commit new code. What Gantt chart software can provide this kind of tightly coupled integration for myself and a small team (2 - 3)?

Answer (score 3):

If you're still interested in trac, I would suggest the [TracJsGanttPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracJsGanttPlugin).  It installs easily, integrates with the popular [TimingAndEstimatingPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TimingAndEstimationPlugin).  The thing I like about this is that you can put a gantt chart anywhere wiki formatting is allowed.  It allows you to expand and collapse levels and provides a decent set of options to control the format.  You can specify any option allowed in a [TracQuery](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracQuery), allowing you to filter on milestone, component, or any other ticket field.

Frankly, Using all the options available in both the [MasterTicketsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MasterTicketsPlugin), [TimingAndEstimatingPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TimingAndEstimationPlugin) and [Subtickets](http://github.com/itota/trac-subtickets-plugin) are probably more than a 2-3 person team can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Redmine is a ticket/issue tracker capable of producing gantt charts. Combined with the backlogs plugin you can get gant charts for Scrum projects on a story and also the task level.

Redmine is found at http://redmine.org/

An online demo is available at http://demo.redmine.org/ - create a new account or use demo / demo as username / password to explore the site. Feel free to add tickets to explore the charting capabilities.

Redmine can be coupled with DCVS like GIT and CCVS like SVN to change an issues status on commit.

Answer (score 0):

Using your current setup the [SchedulingTools Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SchedulingToolsPlugin) provides a gantt chart based on your tickets. However, the project looks to be unmaintained and without a proper English translation.

> A simple scheduling algorithm for
>   tickets.
>
> If each ticket is assigned an effort,
>   they can be scheduled based on their
>   owner and priority and milestone.
>
> Then a Gantt chart can be generated.
>   It displays all scheduled ticketds as
>   usual together with their milestones.
>   The latter ones are display in black
>   if ok or in red, if a ticket in the
>   milestone reaches past the milestones
>   due date.

Comment: Not only is it unmaintained, but you are expected to manually create the 3 fields required by the plugin in your trac.ini, but no indication of what section these custom fields are in, or even something so basic as what name the plugin is referred to in the ini file so that the admin can "Manually enable the Macros".  I would personally avoid this one.

Answer (score 0):

A team that I'm on is currently using [GanttCalendarPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GanttCalendarPlugin). However, we haven't tied anything into SVN at this point, so I don't know how it'll behave under your particular use case. However, it does a great job of displaying Gantt Charts and Calendering your start and end dates for tickets. You'll have to investigate in more depth, but it might be a starting point.